# Can I use use* functions (useState,useRef, useContext) in non rendering components?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to create a utility class for accessing my API more easily. Since the API needs credentials I need to access the global context in which user information is stored.
But this API utilities class is not a rendering component, its simply a class with functions that make calls to the API.

So can I still use all the use* functions from within the functions of this class? Or should I call useContext from within the given component function and pass the credentials to the API class?

Comment: What you need is a custom hook https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Comment: How about giving the credentials to this api class (as a constructor parameter for example) and provide the instance of this class within the Context.

Comment: @sardok thats pretty clever

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova I'll look into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nope, you just can use hooks in the body of your components, not in normal function/class...

pass your credentials through the parameters or get those from another module.

an example for the second case I mentioned (get credentials from another module):

```
import cookie from "js-cookie";

function getToken() {
    return cookie.get("token");
}


function getUserPermissions(id) {
    axios.get("https://blahblahblah.com/.....", {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${getToken()}`
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: >or give those from another module.   
Im not sure what you mean by this. There are no modules in react as far as i know

Comment: I edited the post, this time it probably makes sense...